# no output for .val() on a HTML selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse the content/value of the class "links". Following is the code that I use:

```
function modifyDOM() {
    return document.body.innerHTML;
}

function getAnswers() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: '(' + modifyDOM + ')();'
    }, (results) => {
        var myVar = $(results[0]).find('.links').val();
        return console.log(myVar);
    });
}
```

`results[0]` contains the following example:

```
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title m-b-md">Title</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="eJUTXXLfSGs5UsIwpWPcQxthzqN7nt5F0XdRZEoG">
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            <a href="#">Test 2</a>
            <a href="#">Test 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://test.com/js/app.js"></script>
```

The issue is that `console.log(myVar);` does not output anything.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `var myVar = $(results[0]).find('.links a').text();`  or `.html()`

Comment: `.links` is a `<div>`. It doesn’t have a `value`, thus `val` will return `undefined`. Only input elements have `value`.

Comment: use `.html()` and then process it as required

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments. It totally makes sense the way it was explained and I am kind of embarrassed for even asking, but complete newbie here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.text()` or `.html()` in your code:-

***Simple example:-***

```js
var answers = [];
$('.links a').each(function(){
   answers.push($(this).text()); // can use .html() also
  
});
 console.log(answers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title m-b-md">Title</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="eJUTXXLfSGs5UsIwpWPcQxthzqN7nt5F0XdRZEoG">
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            <a href="#">Test 2</a>
            <a href="#">Test 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://test.com/js/app.js"></script>
```

Note:- So change below line in your code. My be your code starts working:-

```
var myVar = $(results[0]).find('.links a').text(); //or use .html()
```